Can't set instance profile through databricks asset bundle
I doesn't seem to be possible to set an instance profile for the compute cluster that I define for my job. This is databricks.yml in the asset bundle:
targets:
  prod:
    mode: production
    workspace:
      host: https://some_id.cloud.databricks.com
    resources:
      jobs:
        some_job:
          job_clusters:
            - job_cluster_key: job_cluster
              aws_attributes:
                instance_profile_arn: arn:aws:iam::1234:instance-profile/something

Unfortunately this doesn't take effect when I see the job in the UI. If I assign the instance profile manually, it does work, and is also not overwritten when I redeploy the asset bundle.
The command I use to deploy the bundle is databricks bundle deploy -p PROD -t prod. I'm sure my profile is configured correctly because I can deploy the bundle.
Anyone else tackled this issue with databricks asset bundles?

Ah so, if you're defining a new cluster, you gotta include new_cluster: below job_cluster_key:, and then below that the aws_attributes:
So try something like


targets:
  prod:
    mode: production
    workspace:
      host: https://some_id.cloud.databricks.com
    resources:
      jobs:
        some_job:
          job_clusters:
            - job_cluster_key: job_cluster
              new_cluster:
                spark_version: <somethingSomething>
                node_type_id: <hugestOne>
                aws_attributes:
                  instance_profile_arn: arn:aws:iam::1234:instance-profile/something



